# HAProxy (or any lb) - can you redirect based on path without SSL termination?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, haproxy, amazon-elb

I'm looking to decouple the marketing (logged out) portion of a website from the main logged-in app, without having to use subdomains.

I believe I can do this with ACLs in HAProxy, and potentially with other solutions like ELB. However I do not have access to the SSL certificate on the logged in app (generated by a platform as a service).

Is this possible to do without terminating SSL at the load balancer level? If not, how would you go about doing this?

Comment: Not possible. Get a Letsencrypt certificate and use that on your lb.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of (and obvious after reading more). I will have to terminate at the load balancer to do any sort of url or inspection.. that's the whole point of https